# how to check if a control is disabled or not?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a dropdown which is disabled on certain values and enabled on certain values. During save I want to check if it is disabled or not.

I am disabling the dropdown in the following way:

```
ddlSectorRailway.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
```

How to check if the dropdown is disabled or not? I want to save the dropdown value only if it is enabled. How to do this in C#?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not set `Enabled=false`? That way you could check it very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(ddlSectorRailway.Attributes["disabled"]!=null)
{
  if(ddlSectorRailway.Attributes["disabled"]=="disabled")
 {
   //your code 
 }
}
```

Comment: The two conditionals are fighting each other. Just the inner one will suffice as `null == "disabled"` will never be true.

Answer (score 3):

You should code it like this:

```
ddlSectorRailway.Enabled = false;
```

Then on save you can check:

```
if(ddlSectorRailway.Enabled)
{
   //save code
}
```

Comment: +1 I believe it's better to use the control's Enabled property for this. Unfortunately different controls have a different idea of what Enabled means; so what works for a DropDownList might not work elsewhere .. (Generally I find "ClientEnabled", should the control have it, the "better way" to go in most common situations.)